# Operation on subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

This is the question:

**Let $F$, $G$ and $H$ subspace of a vector space be $E$. Determine if the following statement is true:
$$F\cap (H+(F\cap G))=(F\cap H)+(F\cap G)$$**

My answer is:
$$u\in (F\cap H)+(F\cap G)\Rightarrow u = v(\in F\cap H)+w(\in F\cap G)\Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             u\in F \\
             \\ u=v(\in H)+w(\in G) 
             \end{array}
   \right.\Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             u\in F \\
             \\ u\in H+(F\cap G) 
             \end{array}
   \right.\Rightarrow u\in F\cap (H+(F\cap G))\Rightarrow (F\cap H)+(F\cap G)\subseteq F\cap (H+(F\cap G))$$
The other content I think is not fulfilled. I can not think of any counter example. Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u\in F\cap(H+(F\cap G)) \implies \begin{cases}u\in F\\ u\in H+(F\cap G)\end{cases}\\ \implies u=v(\in H) + w(\in F\cap G)\implies u-w=v\in H$

but $u-w\in F$ since $u,w\in F$ and $F$ is a subspace so $v\in F\implies v\in F\cap H$.

Comment: So, $v+w\in (F\cap G)+(F\cap H)$?

Comment: Yes, and thus $u\in (F\cap G) + (F\cap H)$ and so we have $F\cap(H+(F\cap G)) \subseteq (F\cap G) + (F\cap H)$ which is the other half you need for equality.